# Why does oestrogen go from inhibitory to stimulating LH/FSH?

Tags: human-biology, endocrinology, menstrual-cycle

Typically in the menstrual cycle, oestrogen is released from the follicle. The oestrogen goes on to the hypothalamus to have an inhibitory effect on releasing more GnRH and LH/FSH.

However, when all the other follicles in the ovaries have died/atrised, the oestrogen acts as a stimulatory hormone. It increases FSH and LH secretion, to create the LH surge.

Why is this? How can one hormone go from being inhibitory to stimulatory?

Comment: "...suddenly the oestrogen acts as a stimulatory hormone. It increases FSH and LH secretion." What estrogen? What causes menopause? Why does FSH increase with menopause? It's easy to google and what you find will show you where you took a wrong turn in your reasoning.